# Combining several, tagged static files into one GitHub tracked file

Tags: github

I've recently come into management of an old GitHub repo and am trying to get it up to standards. The Repo has a code folder, which contains each 'version' of the code, these have not been modified in any way and are just static slices of the same program, just at different points. Is there any way to retroactively combine these separate files into one tracked file? I'm aware the version history will look messy, but at this point it's better than nothing.

---

Current File Structure

- Code

  - Version 5
  - Version 6
  - Version 7
  - Version 8
  - Version 9
  - Version 10

---

Hopefully Final File Structure

- Code

  - List of files in program